# How to remove a component from JXTaskPane?

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I have the following piece of code where a custom panel is added to the JTaskPane. The pane has a label which gets removed when I click on it. However, my custom panel is not removed. How can I click on the cross in the panel to remove it?

Following is the snapshot. So, in this case, I can remove the "Close" JLabel but I cannot remove the purple label when I click on the "cross" sign

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPane;

public class Test {
    private SRLSearchPanel panel = new SRLSearchPanel();

    class SRLSearchPanel extends JPanel {

        private JXTaskPane filterPanel = new JXTaskPane();
        private JTextField searchField = new JTextField(20);

        public SRLSearchPanel() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            final JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Close");
            filterPanel.add(lbl);
            lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseClicked(e);
                    filterPanel.remove(lbl);
                    filterPanel.revalidate();
                }
            });

            filterPanel.add(searchField);
            add(filterPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

            searchField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    FilterBox filterBox = new FilterBox(searchField.getText());
                    filterPanel.add(filterBox);
                }
            });
        }

        public void removeFilter(FilterBox filterBox) {
            filterPanel.remove(filterBox);
        }
    }

    class FilterBox extends JPanel {

        private static final int PADDING = 2;
        private static final String PAD_STR = "  ";

        private JLabel filterLbl = new JLabel();
        private JButton closeBtn = new JButton("X");

        public FilterBox(String label) {
            filterLbl.setText(PAD_STR + label + PAD_STR);
            closeBtn.setBorderPainted(false);
            closeBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
            closeBtn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            closeBtn.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            System.err.println("Adding action listener "
                    + FilterBox.this.hashCode());
            closeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    panel.removeFilter(FilterBox.this);
                }
            });

            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.add(filterLbl, BorderLayout.WEST);
            this.add(closeBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);

            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseClicked(e);
                    System.err.println("Removing filter");
                    panel.filterPanel.remove(FilterBox.this);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(new Color(0f, 0f, 1f, 0.3f));
            g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() - PADDING,
                    20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test i = new Test();
        i.testRun();
    }

    public void testRun() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        SRLSearchPanel spanel = new SRLSearchPanel();
        frame.add(spanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated in a [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) article you shouldn't override `paint()` method but `paintComponent()` instead for practical purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having a context problem.

First you create an instance variable of `SRLSearchPanel`

```
private SRLSearchPanel panel = new SRLSearchPanel();
```

This is used by your `FilterBox`

But then you create another instance...

```
SRLSearchPanel spanel = new SRLSearchPanel();
frame.add(spanel);
```

This is the one that is actually on the screen, so interacting with `panel` has no effect as it has no relationship to what you've actually put on the screen

Instead, you could try simply requesting that the `FilterBox` be removed from it's parent...

```
closeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        getParent().remove(FilterBox.this);
    }
});
```